# jQuery manually set buttonset radios

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to manually set a radio button to checked, but there is a problem. The code works just fine:

```
$('#'+align+'Text').attr("checked","checked");
```

But when I put jQuery UI into practice and make the radios a buttonset, everything breaks. Again, everything works fine until I put in the .buttonset(), then they look much better than normal radios, but the setting above does not work at all.

**EMPHASIS ON THE FOLLOWING:**
Has anyone been able to manually set a radio button while .buttonset() is active on those radios?

Comment: First off: the `checked` property is a Boolean value, it's set by being either present or not-present. It doesn't require an attribute. Try using: `attr('checked',true)` instead. It might make a difference.

Comment: This is not a problem, it works fine either way when jQuery UI is not used.

Comment: You might want to consider posting a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo that reproduces your problem; that way we can see what's interacting with what.

Comment: @Yottagray - I can't get "buttonset()" to do anything at all in a jsfiddle - what is it supposed to do?  The documentation for "buttonset" is deficient, to say the least ...

Comment: @Pointy - It basically just makes things look pretty, see an example [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio)

Comment: oops sorry  about that (deleted) comment - I see it now.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle where setting the radio button "checked" attribute works perfectly well: http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/Nggxc/3/

Comment: @Yottagray it's not necessary to use that hack - see my answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you need to do is call the "refresh" operation on the button widget after setting the "checked" attribute.

```
$('#'+align+'Text').attr("checked","checked").button('refresh');
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e09sazfp/).

Note that setting the "checked" property can (and, some would say, *should*) be set with the `.prop()` function:

```
$('#' + align + 'Text').prop('checked', true).button('refresh');
```

Comment: Well your workaround wasn't *bad*, really; it's a fine idea that just doesn't happen to be necessary :-)

Comment: Or produce the intended effect, been obsessed with SO lately and have been getting ahead of myself sometimes :-)

Comment: Thank you Pointy and Mark, I really appreciate the effort. Mark's answer was working fine for me, but Pointy your's is a bit better. Thanks again!

Comment: note that this will not trigger change events, for that you can do this:
$('#'+align+'Text').attr("checked","checked").button('refresh').trigger('change');